How to extract all the strings before the second colon from a date-time string?
I have a time data looks like this:
2024-01-26 19:24:40.0
I want to extract everything before the second colon like this: 2024-01-26 19:24
I tried the code as below:
a="2024-01-26 19:24:40.0"
b=sub("(^([^:]+:){2}).*$", "\\1",a)

But the result was like this: 2024-01-26 19:24:
So how to write the code in the right way?

Option 1
> sub("(.*\\d+:\\d+):.*", "\\1", a)
[1] "2024-01-26 19:24"

Option 2
> sub(":\\d+\\.\\d+", "", a)
[1] "2024-01-26 19:24"


Using as.POSIXct
format(as.POSIXct(a), "%F %R")
[1] "2024-01-26 19:24"


The strex package has some regular expression functions to deal with extracting before/after the nth occurrence of a pattern:
library(strex)

str_before_nth("2024-01-26 19:24:40.0", ":", 2)
# [1] "2024-01-26 19:24"

